# To use or not to use CollectSignatureFlow when all the accounts involved in a transaction are on the same node?

Tags: corda

Regarding CollectSignatureFlow with accounts:
In the comments of worldcupticketbooking's file: [DVPAccountsOnSameNode](https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/33773eb0deb95e8ca8bdcf91c3b3f56bfb57b0b1/Accounts/worldcupticketbooking/workflows/src/main/java/com/t20worldcup/flows/DVPAccountsOnSameNode.java) 
its given *Note: though buyer and seller are on the same node still we will have to call CollectSignaturesFlow as the signer is not a Party but an account.*

But [here](https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/b164b6b19d77a8036e779e876efd3311037a4b8a/README.md#modifying-an-existing-cordapp-to-use-accounts) its said that *If your accounts are on the same node that you are running the flow on then they can all be on the signInitialTransaction, however, if one is on another node you need to use a CollectSignatureFlow*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with the comment from the DVP CorDapp that you shared; if all required signers exist on the initiating node, there's no need to call `CollectSignaturesFlow`, instead just pass the keys of the accounts like below:

```java
getServiceHub().signInitialTransaction(transactionBuilder,
                Arrays.asList(getOurIdentity().getOwningKey(), 
                              account1Key, account2Key, account3Key, etc...));
```

Comment: I've checked the same and it indeed works without CollectSignatureFlow

Comment: definitely not needed. @adel-rustum I took the liberty to open a Issue on github https://github.com/corda/samples-java/issues/27 .